# Is it possible to combine Mass transit request-responce with Azure service bus sessions?

Tags: c#, .net, session, azureservicebus, masstransit

I want to implement request-responce pattern using Mass transit with Azure service bus to send "Add product" command and receive some response. In the same time, I would like that command consumers would process products based on "Product type" property that way so each product type would not be processed concurrently.

For example if we have several products of 3 product types in queue and one consumer, then processing order of products could look like following:

1. All products with type 1
2. All products with type 2
3. All products with type 3

(order of product types does not matter)

In my case I am using Azure Service Bus service which has Sessions feature which ?I think should do what I want based on [this info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).

What I don't understand is if it is possible combine sessions with request-responce (i.e. with IRequestClient.GetResponce() and ConsumeContext.RespondAsync() calls pair) and if so, then how should I perform such setup on both producer and consumer.

I tried to set up session for Send operations, but it seems that it is not connected with request-response:

on producer side

```
 x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(connectionString);
                cfg.Send<AddProductRequest>(c => c.UseSessionIdFormatter(s => s.Message.ProductTypeId.ToString("D")));
                
            });
```

on consumer side

```
x.AddConsumer<SubmittedProductConsumer>();
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<SubmittedProductConsumer>();
    
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("myconnectionstring");

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("submit-product-worker", e =>
        {
            e.RequiresSession = true;
            
            e.ConfigureConsumer<SubmittedProductConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});
```